# datatables dataSrc function not called on successful ajax response

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using the [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) plugin to get table data from a server using the ajax Property and transform it using the dataSrc property. My datatables definition:

```
var my_table = $('#my_table').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "/my/url",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": function(json) {
            console.log('json', json);
            return format_my_table_data(json.data);
        }
    },
    "deferLoading": found_rows,
    "data": initial_my_table_data,
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[1, "desc"]],
    "lengthMenu": [
        [25, 50, 100],
        [25, 50, 100]
    ],
    "columns": my_table_columns
});
```

The initial load works fine, and ordering columns and searching works *sometimes* but mostly I see the ajax call return successfully with valid json (I verified using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)) and the table is stuck at "Processing..." sometimes or the table just doesn't change at all.

Json from the server:
`{"recordsTotal":379,"recordsFiltered":378,"draw":25,"data":[{...}]}`

When inspecting the network in the console i can see the ajax request being sent and a response that is similar each time (with a total time between 600ms and 1600ms depending on the number of rows returned) but my console.log inside the dataSrc function isn't called and no javascript errors in the console.  What gives?

Comment: Are your returning the same `draw` parameter that was received in request on the server? Plugin may discard response if `draw` values in request and response don't match.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com what about the case when the number of returned results is less than the draw value, say you only were able to find 3 rows should the draw value be 3?  Or maybe i am misinterpreting what "draw" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should return `draw` parameter with the same value of the `draw` parameter in the request. I believe it starts at `1` and then increments with every request.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data):

> `draw`
>
> The draw counter that this object is a response to - from the `draw` parameter sent as part of the data request. Note that it is **strongly recommended for security reasons** that you cast this parameter to an integer, rather than simply echoing back to the client what it sent in the `draw` parameter, in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Thank you, i misread the draw attribute as the number of returned rows not the number of table draws.  I changed my returned draw value to just be whatever was being passed in and it works now.